# Magento Price of delivery should vary on country. How can I do that?

Tags: php, magento, enterprise

When a customer is going through the checkout phase... 
How can the price of the delivery a customer will pay, CHANGE/UPDATE depending on the country they are based in with the use of Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shipping method that comes with default Magento is good enough to achieve what you're asking for.

Go to System > Configuration > Shipping Methods(Sales).
Select Website in Current Configuration Scope. and then go to Table Rates. You will see Export and Import CSV. Prepare your data in CSV format and import. Then you are ready to go.

If you have multiple shipping method that the customer can choose from then there are some free modules on the magento connect. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html.
It is useful when you have different shipping schemes such as 
1. Price vs destination
2. Weight vs destination
3. Num of items vs destination

Then you can use default for one of the above, and the extension to achieve some of the remaining ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table Rate` shipping method, provided as default in Magento, you have to upload a `csv` of rates for all countries for which you want a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create different shipping method for different countries if you are a developer. But I don't think that's an ideal solution if you have more countries. You can go for http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

This will meet your requirement.