# Magento Shipping Methods by Region

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to make Shipping Methods depend by Region/State.
I take a look in to app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/ there are 3 files that I think might be needed to make things happen:
etc/system.xml - contains configuration:

```
  223                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  224                          </sallowspecific>
  225:                         <specificcountry translate="label">
  226                              <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
  227                              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
  ...
  232                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  233                              <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
  234:                         </specificcountry>
  235                          <showmethod translate="label">
  236                              <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
  ...
  312                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  313                          </sallowspecific>
  314:                         <specificcountry translate="label">
  315                              <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
  316                              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
  ...
  321                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  322                              <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
  323:                         </specificcountry>
  324                          <showmethod translate="label">
  325                              <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
  ...
  445                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  446                          </sallowspecific>
  447:                         <specificcountry translate="label">
  448                              <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
  449                              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
  ...
  454                              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
  455                              <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
  456:                         </specificcountry>
  457                          <showmethod translate="label">
  458                              <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
```

Another files:
Model/Carrier/Abstract.php

```
/**
 * Return delivery confirmation types of carrier
 *
 * @param Varien_Object|null $params
 * @return array
 */
public function getDeliveryConfirmationTypes(Varien_Object $params = null)
{
    return array();
}

public function checkAvailableShipCountries(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    $speCountriesAllow = $this->getConfigData('sallowspecific');
    /*
    * for specific countries, the flag will be 1
    */
    if ($speCountriesAllow && $speCountriesAllow == 1){
         $showMethod = $this->getConfigData('showmethod');
         $availableCountries = array();
         if($this->getConfigData('specificcountry')) {
            $availableCountries = explode(',',$this->getConfigData('specificcountry'));
         }
         if ($availableCountries && in_array($request->getDestCountryId(), $availableCountries)) {
             return $this;
         } elseif ($showMethod && (!$availableCountries || ($availableCountries
             && !in_array($request->getDestCountryId(), $availableCountries)))
         ){
               $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
               $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
               $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
               $errorMsg = $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg');
               $error->setErrorMessage($errorMsg ? $errorMsg : Mage::helper('shipping')->__('The shipping module is not available for selected delivery country.'));
               return $error;
         } else {
             /*
            * The admin set not to show the shipping module if the devliery country is not within specific countries
            */
            return false;
         }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Last one:
Model/Shipping.php

```
/**
 * Collect rates of given carrier
 *
 * @param string                           $carrierCode
 * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
 * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping
 */
public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
{
    /* @var $carrier Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract */
    $carrier = $this->getCarrierByCode($carrierCode, $request->getStoreId());
    if (!$carrier) {
        return $this;
    }
    $carrier->setActiveFlag($this->_availabilityConfigField);
    $result = $carrier->checkAvailableShipCountries($request);
    if (false !== $result && !($result instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Error)) {
        $result = $carrier->proccessAdditionalValidation($request);
    }
```

I guess i need to somehow change Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier, $availableCountries, and 'specific country' on regions, but i need some help with this.
I know i shouldn't edit core files, so i think if i'll figure out how to make Shipping Methods by Region i'll put changes in to local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your Mission =>" make Shipping Methods depend by Region/State ".

There is no need alter core files to achieve this. Your post is not very clear. But, as far as I understand, in the checkout process, you want different shipping methods/price to come up according to the selected shipping country/state, right.

please refer to my answer here : [Magento Price of delivery should vary on country. How can I do that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600365/magento-price-of-delivery-should-vary-on-country-how-can-i-do-that/24603237#24603237)

Once you get hold of managing the csv structure for shipping purpose, I'm sure everything will be easy.

Comment: Unfortunetly that's not what i'm looking for.
I want to make Flat rate specific for London and Liverpool.
All Table Rates for all UK cities except London.
And Free Shipping set only for London City.

Comment: maintain table rate for all cities including London and set the price for london to ZERO. Will that not work? Even if your shipping rate depends on price or destination, you could manage a flat rate kinda column for London only and use Any Text/Label in the CSV.